# SQL query sum()/join/order by/ - what's wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I learning SQL, using Northwind example database and I'm completely stuck on very simple problem:
I want to list all products name in one column and total quantities sold for each product in second column.
First, I did this:

```
select p.ProductId
    ,sum(od.Quantity) as TotalQuantity 
from Products p  
join [Order Details] od 
    on p.ProductId=od.Productid
group by p.ProductId
```

and that's ok - I have product id's and total quantities, but when I try something like this:

```
select p.productid
    ,p.ProductName
    , sum(od.quantity) as TotalQuantity
from products p  
join [Order details] od 
    on p.productid=od.productid
group by p.productid
```

I get error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'products.ProductName' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use aggregate functions (like `sum`) you have to `group by` every other field in `select`

You have to modify your query as follows

```
select p.productid, p.ProductName, sum(od.quantity) as TotalQuantity from
products p  join [Order details] od on p.productid=od.productid
group by p.productid, p.ProductName
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you will never going to get different ProductNames for a single ProductId, you can also try:

```
select p.productid
, min(p.ProductName) as ProductName
, sum(od.quantity) as TotalQuantity
from products p  
join [Order details] od 
    on p.productid=od.productid
group by p.productid
```